# Display messages in test/unit result

Tags: ruby, assertions, testunit, rescue

I want to display the message after test is passed. Where i need to print the message so that i can get in result of test.

```
require 'test/unit'

class MyTest < Test::Unit::TestCase
  def sample
    begin
      count = 0
      5.times do 
        assert(true)
        count = count + 1
      end
    rescue
    ensure
    print "Total number of times: 5, Success count: 3 , Failures count: 2 "
    end
  end
end
```

I want to get some thing like this

```
Loaded suite
Started
"Total number of times: 5, Success count: 3 , Failures count: 2 "
.
Finished in 0.0 seconds.

1 tests, 5 assertions, 0 failures, 0 errors
```

Can anyone help me ?

Comment: May I ask you why you want to print a message there? Basically the idea of unit tests is that they should be green without distraction.

Comment: @SebastianG I don't want to raise error for my specific test(runs 5 or 10 times) then print number of success and failures times. Is there any way to do it.

Comment: Add another counter and replace `assert(true)` with `success_count += 1 if true` but as I said I don't think that's a good idea. Your tests shouldn't have any output and instead fail if one of the iterations fails.